# How to compare 10 big XML files?

Tags: xml, linux, git, compare

I have 10 big XML files and some files are different from others (it represents data in a step of the process).

How to compare them **AUTOMATICALLY**?

I do know I can compare them manually using tools like [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge) or eyes, but I don't like that approach.

I would like it to do it on a Windows machine, but I have [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) installed.

I think I can somehow use **git diff** to do that, but ... how?

Comment: Do you want to know the differences, or just which ones are identical in content?

Comment: True. Might belong to superusers instead.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp How can you do that without programming? please, explain.

Comment: This is very much programming related, for god sake, it's a revision control system. Which I use daily, this question is relevant to my interests.

Comment: @foo please also migrate all git questions to superuser, its just an app.

Comment: @01: a) it wasn't a git question when it was opened, b) I do not have that privilege of migrating questions yet, sorry. Would do if I could.

Comment: @01 automatically without programming? There exist tools that are used for automating different operations (including running some diff with parameters) but they are not at all programming tools.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp please post a meta question to migrate all git questions, they can do it automatically without programming.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to know is the difference, the simplest (not fastest!) will be to do a hash over them and compare the results. md5sum yourfile*.xml and see which entries are identical.

It would be more efficient to compare them in a different way, but I don't think there are standard tools for that - a small program would do, however.

```
Open all files to be compared
Loop over the character indices
    fetch character from each, compare
    remove from list those which are not identical / group those who have the same
```

So on the first difference, you can narrow down your search, depending on what you want to do. Calculating a checksum/hash will do this over the entire files by default; you wrote about *large* files.

I'd go with the md5sum (shasum, ...) for now, though.

Comment: Or, just use `diff`, `wc` and `uniq` (to see / count / visualize the actual differences).

Answer (score 2):

Do you need an XML-aware comparison, e.g. one that recognizes that attribute order is not significant? If so, you can compare the files by parsing them and using the deep-equal() function in XPath or XQuery. Alternatively, you can turn the files into XML canonical form and then compare the canonicalized files bytewise.

If you need an analysis of the differences, rather than merely a boolean value telling you they are different, there is a product called DeltaXML that specializes in this. It's not free.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to determine quickly whether the files are the same or not you might consider using a hashing algorithm - md5 each file and compare the resulting hashes?

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest way to compare two files is to use `diff file1 file2`. You can add `-b` and `-B` options to ignore whitespace and white line differences : `diff -bB file1 file2`. try `man diff`.

If you want to do that for a lot of files, use a script.

`git diff` is relevant if you compare two revision of the same file.

my2c